# how to update the gridview automatically without using timer control when there is a change in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to update the gridview automatically without using timer control when there is a change in database table.

please let me comment if anyone can't get my question .

thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that using timer is because we do not know when a change happens to the database.   
If you want to update the database based on changed, there have to be something to monitor the database in the 1st place.
So if database changes are done by only your application, then it might be easier.
If not, I can say that it might be hard to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the application to detect a change in the database it must either monitor the relevant tables or somehow be notified of changes in the database by an outside source. Using a timer to poll the database for changes is one option. Having another program perform that task and then notify your application is another way to do it. Some databases, like [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/), has the ability to post events that your application can listen to.

In my experience having the database post events is by far the easiest solution but it of course requires you to use a database with that capability. You should probably also consider your design. Why do you need the database to notify the GUI? Is it really necessary or just an easy way to have the GUI updated? Take some time to think about what roles the different layers in an application should fill before deciding on this strategy.

That being said sometimes having the database instigate GUI changes or other actions is perfectly acceptable. If the database is shared amongst multiple users and each user needs to be notified of actions taken by the other users it could be a good solution. Personally I'd try to find other ways of communicating before settling on the data driven approach but in some cases ther's really not that many other viable options.

Answer (score 0):

actually when the application needs it queries the database but in this situation the database needs to cause events.though the database can cause events using triggers but that has some limitations and the scope of the change taking place is limited within the database.to show a change in the application(here updation of gridview) can only take place if a call is made from the application only.this can be done using timer controls from the application .but without sending a call to the database from the application its impossible

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows service that will run offline from the application...
The service will query the db and will update file in the system when there is a change...
In the application you can use cahce dependency on the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you could look into Windows Communication Foundation and some of the examples they they have.